# If I have 10 gems, can I still reserve a card?

Tags: splendor

In the game 'Splendor', if I have 10 gems at the beginning of my turn, can I still reserve a card and get a yellow gem (and discard another to respect the 10 gems limitation) ? Or it's not possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

Very simply, if at the end of your turn you have more than ten tokens discard down to ten by returning your choice of tokens to their respective piles.  The *only* time when having more than ten tokens is relevant is very specifically at the end of your turn.

From [the rulebook](https://cdn.1j1ju.com/medias/7f/91/ba-splendor-rulebook.pdf):

> **Selecting tokens**
>
> > A player can never have more than 10 tokens at the end of their turn (including jokers). If this happens, they must return tokens until they only have 10 left. A player can return all or some of those they’ve just drawn. The tokens owned by a player must be visible by all players at all times.
> >
> > ***Reminder***: players may not take 2 tokens of the same color if
> >     there are less than 4 tokens available of that color.

Comment: For reference I have confirmed this with the ios version where I had 10 gems, reserved a card and had to return a gem when I got to 11.

Comment: A player can return all or some of those they’ve just drawn.  -- and also they can return tokens they have drawn previously. This is tremendously important in a two player game where taking just one token is enough to stop the other play from taking two and yet you can get rid of it easily when you are up to ten. (Unlike reserved cards which you can never get rid of unless you build them.)